# Print row in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

What can I change so that I will get a list of only the first row?
i.e

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

I have tried the below:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
    [3, 5, 7, 9],
    [4, 6, 8, 10],
    [5, 7, 9, 11]]
for index in range(len(matrix)):
    print(index,matrix[index][0])

0 1
1 3
2 4
3 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
print(index,matrix[0][index])
```

instead of:

```
print(index,matrix[index][0])
```

This is because the first index is associated with the outer list (the rows). `matrix[index]` returns an entire row, and then slicing it further returns elements from that row.

You should also change:

```
for index in range(len(matrix)):
```

to:

```
for index in range(len(matrix[0])):
```

for the same reason.  Since it's a square matrix, it'll work out either way, but that's just luck.  Actually, it'd be best to just do this instead for simplicity:

```
for i, e in enumerate(matrix[0]):
    print(i, e)
```

On each iteration of the loop, `enumerate()` yields a tuple consisting of the index and the element together.  If you don't need the index, you could further simplify to:

```
for e in matrix[0]:
    print(e)
```

You typically only need to use `range()` if you aren't already starting with a list (or something else that's iterable).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
    [3, 5, 7, 9],
    [4, 6, 8, 10],
    [5, 7, 9, 11]]

for index in range(len(matrix)):
    print(index,matrix[0][index])
```

You were trying to get the first element from each individual list, the code above will get all elements from the first list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `matrix` is a list of rows:

```
print(matrix[0])
```

Or if you want one item per line:

```
for value in matrix[0]:
    print(value)
```

And if you want the index:

```
for index, value in enumerate(matrix[0]):
    print(index, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix = [
      [1, 2, 3, 4],
      [3, 5, 7, 9],
      [4, 6, 8, 10],
      [5, 7, 9, 11]
    ]
```

`matrix[0]` gives you the first row, just iterate over it like this:

```
# ONLY ITERATING OVER THE FIRST ROW
for item in matrix[0]:
  print(item)
```